# Backend for Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, backend

I'm new to Ionic and Angular, so I'm doing basic things with tabs, tables... The thing is that I want to implement a timetable so that it can be updated from a remote site, and everytime the user requests an update the app timetable updates.

How could I go for it? I thought of a remote server in php for example where you add events and remove events, so it connects and gets the data from there... But how could I make "dynamic tables" in the case there are more events or less events?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Backand](http://www.backand.com).

They have full integration with Ionic.

You can see example at ionic blog.

http://blog.ionic.io/creating-an-ionic-app-with-mysql-and-backand/

Answer (score 0):

use a hosted service like Parse, Firebase or Kinvey to get started

Comment: Already got a Parse service, I just don't know how to go on. The only thing I can think of is creating an array-like structure and print it with ng-repeat

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: I'm trying to let's say, get a table with a name, time and description online. Then, inside the app, just update and parse the results from the place into the app.